# Is it possible to have tool like splunk read log files produced by each Jboss app server running as docker?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to have tool like splunk read log files produced by each Jboss app server running as docker ?
Since each docker container has its own namespace.. how do you read their produce in another container.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of docker logging drivers available.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

Specifically for splunk here - 
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/splunk/